# Поток который должен ждать определенное время java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть поток "А" , который обращается к ресурсу "Б". Ресурс "Б" может использоваться другим потоком. В таком случае поток "А" должен впасть в режим ожидания. В режиме ожидания есть два варианта: 
а) Ресурс "Б"(именно ресурс "Б") обратиться к потоку "А" и тот выйдя из ожидания начнет работать с ресурсом 
б) Поток "А" прождет какое то заданное время и при превышении этого времени - остановит свою работу(т.е. существование).

Для реализации задумки варианта "б)" было решено прикрутить таймер к потоку и при превышении времени поток просто вышел бы из вечного цикла. Проблема возникла в том что таймер имеет особенность: При запуске метод который ему заложили включается один раз ДО того как начнется отсчет времени. А нам надо сделать так что бы при запуске таймера пошел тайминг и только по истечении которого включился бы метод отключающий поток.

Есть ли класс Таймера который выполнит код ТОЛЬКО после того как пройдет какое то время?

Answer (score 2):

Ваша задача, это классическая проблема `producer-consumer`. Решить ее можно при помощи очереди, все необходимое присутствует в стандартной библиотеке и почти ничего не нужно писать самому. Выглядеть это будет так:

Класс создающий какой то результат (Ресурс Б):

```
private static class Producer<T> {
    private final BlockingQueue<T> queue;

    private Producer(BlockingQueue<T> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run(T element) {
        try {
            T result = somethingTooHard(element);
            queue.put(result);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private T somethingTooHard(T element) throws InterruptedException {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        return element;
    }
}
```

Класс получающий результат (Поток А):

```
private static class Consumer<T> {
    private final BlockingQueue<T> queue;

    private Consumer(BlockingQueue<T> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            T element = queue.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (element == null)
                System.out.println("вышли из ожидания по таймауту");
            else
                System.out.println(String.format("получили элемент: %s", element));

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

И метод для запуска их вместе:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(2);

    executor.execute(() -> new Producer<>(queue).run("hello world"));
    executor.execute(() -> new Consumer<>(queue).run());
}
```